# C# double-quoted path name being escaped when read from file

Tags: c#, file-io, escaping

I am trying to read in a text input file that contains a list of filenames (one per line). However, I am running into an issue if the user double-quotes the path (because it has a space in it).

For example, a normal input file might have:
C:\test\test.tiff
C:\test\anothertest.tiff
C:\test\lasttest.tiff

These get read in fine by my code ("C:\\test\\test.tiff" etc)

However, if I have the following input file:
"C:\test with spaces\test.tiff"
"C:\test with spaces\anothertest.tiff"
"C:\test with spaces\lasttest.tiff"

These get read in double-quotes and all ("\"C:\\test with spaces\\test.tiff\"" etc). This becomes a problem when I try to open the files (I understandably get invalid character exceptions). My question is, how do I fix this? I want to allow users to input quoted strings and handle them correctly. My first impression was to just write a little method that strips off beginning or ending quotes, but I thought there might be a better way.

Comment: That's pretty much the only way to do it. You could possibly use a regular expression, but for something this simple I'd just write a function that manually checks for the existence of the surrounding quotes and strip them if they are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a `RegEx` where a simple `Replace` will do:

```
var s = s.Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

> My first impression was to just write
>   a little method that strips of
>   beginning or ending quotes...

Yeah, that's what I'd do, too. =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using string literals?

string bob = @"c:\some file\some document";

The @ escapes these backslash problems.

Comment: The problem is this input data from users. I could do this if I were hardcoding the strings, but this is being read in from a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one file per line you can just do `Regex.Replace(PathLine,"\"","")`

If you don't you will need to split every time `PathLine.Split(new string[] { "\" ", "\"\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` then strip out the beginning "

Answer (score -1):

I think RegEx is quite heavy compared to a simple replace, so

```
File.ReadAllText(path.Replace('"',''));
```

Or similar would be my suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't work: `string.Replace` takes either two chars or two strings. Since `''` isn't a char, if you want to replace something by nothing you have to do `Replace("\"", "")`.